# xsl копирование элемента в xml из одних узлов в другие

Tags: xslt

Прошу помощи у знатоков XSLT.
Есть задача по корректировке xml-файлов - необходимо переносить текст из одного узла в другой с созданием элементов (прошу прощения за техническую неграмотность).
Описание задачи на примере:

Исходный XML:

```
<root>
 <wo uuid="1">
    <title>event1</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text1</name>
        <value>val1</value>
    </obj>
 </wo>
 <wo uuid="2">
    <title>event2</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text2</name>
        <value>val2</value>
    </obj>
 </wo>
</root>
```

Задача: значение текста в `<title> </title>` должно быть скопировано в узел `<obj></obj>`.

Необходимый выходной XML:

```
<root>
 <wo uuid="1">
    <title>event1</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text1</name>
        <value>val1</value>
        <reference>event1</reference>
    </obj>
 </wo>
 <wo uuid="2">
    <title>event2</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text2</name>
        <value>val2</value>
        <reference>event2</reference>
    </obj>
 </wo>
</root>
```

Уточнение: в XML-файле может быть несколько узлов `wo`, с разными значениями `title`.

Собственно, в том, что узлов несколько для меня и стало проблемой. Предполагаю, что необходимо задействовать какой-то цикл, т.к. копировать удается только значение первого `<title>event1</title>` во все последующие узлы:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/wo/obj/value">
  <xsl:for-each select="current()">
     <xsl:copy-of select ="current()" />
     <xsl:element name="reference">
       <xsl:value-of select="/root/wo/title/text()" />
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Получаемый результат (некорректный):

```
<root>
<wo uuid="1">
    <title>event1</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text1</name>
        <value>val1</value>
        <reference>event1</reference>
    </obj>
</wo>
<wo uuid="2">
    <title>event2</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text2</name>
        <value>val2</value>
        <reference>event1</reference>
    </obj>
</wo>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать, чтобы получить желаемый результат. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строка

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/wo/title/text()" />
```

возвращает значение первого элемента в документе. А вам нужно обратиться к "элементу-дяде"

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../title/text()" />
```

А еще лучше заменить шаблон

```
<xsl:template match="/root/wo/obj/value">
```

на такой

```
<xsl:template match="obj">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <reference>
      <xsl:value-of select="../title"/>
    </reference>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```