# xsl копирование элемента в xml из одних узлов в другие часть 2

Tags: xslt

Данный вопрос является продолжением другого: [xsl копирование элемента в xml из одних узлов в другие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889787/xsl-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-xml-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5)

т.к. в жизни все не так просто, задача усложняется.

И так, необходимо копировать значения `<title> </title>` в узлы `<obj></obj>`, создавая новые элементы `<refrence> </refrence>`:

Исходный xml:

```
<root>
 <wo uuid="1">
    <title>event1</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text1</name>
        <value>val1</value>
    </obj>
 </wo>
 <wo uuid="2">
    <title>event2</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text2</name>
        <value>val2</value>
    </obj>
 </wo>
</root>
```

Используем xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/> 

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wo/obj">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <reference>
        <xsl:value-of select="../title"/>
        </reference>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

получаем выходной xml:

```
<root>
    <wo uuid="1">
        <title>event1</title>
        <obj>
            <name>text1</name>
            <value>val1</value>
            <reference>event1</reference>
        </obj>
    </wo>
    <wo uuid="2">
        <title>event2</title>
        <obj>
            <name>text2</name>
            <value>val2</value>
            <reference>event2</reference>
        </obj>
    </wo>
</root>
```

Казалось бы все хорошо, но, бывают исходные файлы, в которых в некоторых узлах `<wo>`:

1. Отсутствуют `<obj></obj>`.
   В этом случае `<obj>` должен быть создан и добавлен `<reference>`. В примере - wo uuid 2.
2. Узел `<obj></obj>` также присутствует в других узлах со своими `<refrence>`.
   В примере - wo uuid 3 узел `<ws>`. В этом случае `<refrence>event3</refrence>` должен быть создан именно в узле `<obj></obj>` для которого родитель `wo`.

Пример исходного xml "с приколюхой":

```
<root>

 <wo uuid="1">
    <title>event1</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text1</name>
        <value>val1</value>
    </obj>
 </wo>

 <wo uuid="2">
    <title>event2</title>
 </wo>

 <wo uuid="3">
    <title>event3</title>
    <ws>
        <head>h3</head>
        <obj>
            <reference>ref3</reference>
        </obj>
    </ws>
    <obj>
        <name>text3</name>
        <value>val3</value>
    </obj>
 </wo>
</root>
```

Необходимо получить xml (в котором в любом узле `<wo>` есть узел `<obj>` с элементом `<reference>`:

```
<root>

 <wo uuid="1">
    <title>event1</title>
    <obj>
        <name>text1</name>
        <value>val1</value>
        <reference>event1</reference>
    </obj>
 </wo>

 <wo uuid="2">
    <title>event2</title>
    <obj>
        <reference>event2</reference>
    </obj>
 </wo>

 <wo uuid="3">
    <title>event3</title>
    <ws>
        <head>h3</head>
        <obj>
            <reference>ref3</reference>
        </obj>
    </ws>
    <obj>
        <name>text3</name>
        <value>val3</value>
        <refrence>event3</refrence>
    </obj>
 </wo>
</root>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти решение.

Пробовал использовать и `<xsl:if>`, и шаблон с проверкой узла `<xsl:template match="wo[not(/obj)]">` - все время какой-то из "сценариев" некорректно трансформируется.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобрался:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/> 

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wo/obj">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <reference>
            <xsl:value-of select="../title"/>
        </reference>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wo[not(obj)]">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <obj>
        <reference>
        <xsl:value-of select="./title"/>
        </reference>
        </obj>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

может кому поможет